# Как хранить смайлики в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, mysqlconnector, pymysql

При попытке загрузить смайлик в БД, пишет: "1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x89' for column 'last_name' at row 1"

Нашел вариант про utf8mb4. Перевел сервер,БД,таблицы и поля в utf8mb4, все равно ошибка.

Если в Python при соед. указываю charset = utf8mb4, то получаю ошибку: "1273 (HY000): Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'".

Нашел единственный вариант, который сработал это в Python указать:

```
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4')
cursor.execute("SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4")
cursor.execute("SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4")
```

Тогда всё работает. Но тут неудобно везде писать эти три строки, возможно ли их как-то прописать в настройках mysql?

Уже на самом деле запутался...
P.S.
Версия сервера: 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось, что...
Python3 mysql.connector версии 8.0.6 не поддерживает utf8mb4.
Переустановил на
» mysql.connector.version
'2.1.7' - работает.